# How can I find out what Gen of NVME my machine supports (what PCI express version)?

Tags: pci, nvme

Looking at Amazon there is PCIe Gen 3 NVME and PCIe Gen 4 NVME for sale. I don't see this even mentioned on the [Wikipedia page for NVM Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express#Specifications). Is there a method to query what the system I am on supports?

Comment: *dmidecode -t slot* ?

Comment: @MC68020 - not really... [here is what `dmidecode` says about my system](https://bsd-hardware.info/index.php?probe=b898297110&log=dmidecode) ... as you can see all slots are detected as either x1 or x2 (no mention of PCIe version). I recommend reading https://www.linux.com/news/dmidecode-whats-it-good/ where Joe Barr asks both the project leader of `dmidecode` and Linux Torvalds about the reliability and use of _dmi_ info.

Answer (score 4):

The two parameters you're looking for are the PCI Express Version (or Generation) and the number of lanes. Here's a summary of PCIe releases:

```
----------------------------------------
Generation   Released      Speed
----------------------------------------
PCIe 1.0      2003        2  GT/s
PCIe 2.0      2007        5  GT/s
PCIe 3.0      2010        8  GT/s
PCIe 4.0      2017        16 GT/s
PCIe 5.0      2019        32 GT/s
PCIe 6.0      2021        64 GT/s
```

I don't know of a way to directly report the PCIe version of the NVMe controller but you can get the link speed and, based on the above table, it's easy to figure it out. Run `lspci -vv` and look  for `LnkCap` under the NVMe controller capabilities; or if you know the device `BDF`<sup>1</sup> you can use it with `-s` e.g.

```
lspci -vv -s 03:00.0
```

```
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Device (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
[...]
   LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L1 <8us
           ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
[...]
   LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x2
           TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
[...]
```

`LnkCap` shows link `Cap`ability: `PCIe x4` @ `8GT/s` i.e. this motherboard supports `PCIe v3.0 x4`
`LnkSta` shows link `Sta`tus: `PCIe x2` @ `5GT/s` i.e. the ssd in that slot is a `PCIe v2.0 x2` nvme.

---

You can get the same information via `sysfs`:
speed:

```
cat /sys/class/pci_bus/0000:03/device/0000:03:00.0/max_link_speed
```

```
8.0 GT/s PCIe
```

number of lanes:

```
cat /sys/class/pci_bus/0000:03/device/0000:03:00.0/max_link_width
```

```
4
```

Replace `max` in the above commands with `current` to see the link speed for the currently installed nvme.

---

<sup>1: `BDF` stands for `B`us_number`D`evice_number`F`unction_number of the form `02:1b.0`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken that depends on the PCI-E revision of your motherboard chipset + CPU support + how M.2 slots are wired. AFAIK there's no way to query it beforehand - consult with your MB manual.

Comment: SInce you are known running nvidia drivers, may I ask what does *nvidia-smi --query-gpu=pcie.link.gen.max,pcie.link.gen.current --format=csv* report on your system. On mine it reports *[N/A], [N/A]* but I am running on very old hardware.

Comment: GPU: GTX 1660 Ti, X570 based motherboard (i.e. with PCIe 4 but my GPU is PCIe 3 only). Output: `pcie.link.gen.max, pcie.link.gen.current [new line]
3, 1` Running NVIDIA drivers `525.60.11`, Linux kernel `6.0.15`.